# Running git pull from a php script

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ssh, permissions, git

I was trying the [Perfect Workflow, with Git, GitHub, and SSH](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh/comment-page-1/#comment-365925), but it seems i can't run `git pull`. I've tried `git status` and it's fine.

When i `git pull 2>&1` i get:

> error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

I tried to chmod .git dir to 777 with no luck.

When i run `whoami` from the browser it shows me: `apache`

--- EDIT ---

I just did `chown apache:apache -R .git` and now i get:

> Could not create directory '/.ssh'. Host key verification failed.
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Could not create directory '/.ssh'. Host key verification failed. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Read and consider your error message. Host keys are stored in the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file. Your Apache user has "/" as its home directory, and it definitely doesn't and shouldn't have write access to the root.

I suggest that you create a user account for this... maybe `gitpull-user` or something. Make sure it has a usable home directory, even if it's somewhere atypical. Login as that user and create a shell script that accomplishes what you're trying to do as that user. Of course, you'll also have to copy your appropriate id_rsa key to the user's account, etc.

Configure sudo to launch that script by adding this line to /etc/sudoers

```
apache ALL = (gitpull-user) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh`
```

and also if you're having "No TTY" issues:

```
Defaults:apache !requiretty
```

Change your PHP script to call `sudo -u gitpull-user ./script.sh`

---

It would be possible to change Apache's home directory to a "real" location and just drop the key in there, but that would expose a risk where your data would have to be owned by apache and the key could be read if the daemon were compromised. Establishing a second user provides a level of isolation.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jeff Ferland. Unfortunately i dont have the knowledge to do that. Appreciated the effort.

Comment: useradd gitpull-user; chown gitpull-user script; chmod 4755 script.

Comment: Thanks again Jeff. I did that. But nothing happened.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem but I am on nginx. A step by step approach should really help!

Answer (score 0):

Run:

`sudo -u apache ssh YOURGITHOST`

Basically, the apache user doesn't know what the remote servers SSH host key is, and it can't prompt you to accept it.  There's other ways to do this, but this is the one I remember best.

Comment: I run sudo -u apache ssh github.com

`Could not create directory '/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ##############################.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two closely-related problems:

1. The user apache is running as can't write to the normal location for its `~/.ssh` directory (because on CentOS Apache's home directory is `/`, and obviously we don't want the web server just putting things wherever it wants in the filesystem).
2. Github wants a public key to authenticate you.

There's a fix that should be able to handle both of these cases: `git` uses the `GIT_SSH` environment variable (if it's set) to determine what command to run as "ssh", so you just need to tweak that environment variable to tell SSH two things:  Where to look for its `known_hosts` file, and what public key to use to authenticate with.

Add
`export GIT_SSH="ssh -oUserKnownHostsFile=/some/path/to/known_hosts -i /some/path/to/private_key"`
to your script and things *should* work OK (obviously substitute a path Apache can write to for the dummy paths in my example).

Note that you will have to connect to the remote host once as the Apache user to create and populate the `known_hosts` file.  You can do that by running the script from the command line and dealing with the interactive prompt when it comes up.  If you run the script a second time you should not have any interactive prompts do deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to pull from a GIT repository using exec() in a webserver PHP script, too.
The remote repository was checked out read-only under a different user.

My main problem was that when running the webserver PHP script the EXEC result variables from the PULL were completely empty - I just could tell that the PULL did not happen, no further error messages, nothing. A simple 'git help' did work, though.

What fixed the problem was the following:

First I make the webserveruser owner of the repository directory:

```
chown -R <webserveruser>:<webusergroup> <repodir>
```

Usually can't login to the webserver user, so I had assign a shell first:

```
usermod -s /bin/bash <webserveruser>
```

Login as webserver user:

```
su <webserveruser>
```

Then change to the repodirectory and do a manual pull :

```
cd <repodir>
git pull
```

Exit the webserver user and go back to root and disable the shell on the webserver user again:

```
exit
usermod -s /bin/false <webserveruser>
```

As strange as it sounds: After that the read-only PULL using the webserver script worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same Question like yours.
and i try to do below

1. you should know the 'role' of http execute. Just like your 'apache'
2. create your ssh key `sudo -u apache ssh-keygen -t rsa` and the path of the key will be show in the cmd screen.
3. go to the path and `cat id_rsa.pub`, copy your key and post to the github or gitlab
4. finally, because your server dont know the host of git server. So you should do below:
   `sudo -u http ssh <git host>` ，git host maybe github.com or gitlab.com
   Type 'yes' after you used the cmd. And you will find the server create a file named 'known_hosts' in '.ssh/'
5. To try your php exec('git pull origin master'), it is ok.

--

Answer (score 0):

If you're using https instead of ssh you can specify user/password directly in the request:

git clone:

```
$output = shell_exec ("git clone https://user:password@github.com:user/repo.git");
```

git pull:

```
$output = shell_exec("git pull https://user:password@github.com:user/repo.git");
```

sample php code

```
<?php

$outputs =  shell_exec('git pull https://user:password@github.com:user/repo.git master');
echo "<pre>$outputs</pre>";
?>
```

`$outputs` it will show the last commit result.

Then you add permission for your project folder

```
chown -R <webserveruser>:<webusergroup> <repodir>
```

Restart the apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

it will work from the browser you can run the php file. the code will update